# Problem with header, footer and page number

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, page

I am using packages `fancyhdr`and `fancy`to customize header and footer.

```
.....
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Team no.}
\rhead{Problem no.}
\cfoot{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\title{Problem Name}
\author{Team no. \\ Problem no.}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
....
```

I wanna remove only the footer(here 'page number') from the 'table of contents' pages. Also, I like to use 'page number' in the format of "Page x of y". 
How can I do?

TIA

Comment: All of the pages with the `\tableofcontents` should have its page number removed?

Comment: You second question is answered here: [How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227/5764)

Comment: yes, @Werner . 
All of the pages with the `\tableofcontents` should have its page number removed.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}`

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I had trouble turning `\pagestyle{fancy}` off and on again.  It was easier to create two new pagestyles instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\fancypagestyle{nofoot}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields
  \lhead{Team no.}
  \rhead{Problem no.}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\fancypagestyle{foot}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields
  \lhead{Team no.}
  \rhead{Problem no.}
  \cfoot{Page \thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Problem Name}
\author{Team no. \\ Problem no.}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\newpage
\pagestyle{nofoot}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagestyle{foot}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution isn't affected by `\pagestyle{fancy}`, right?.

Comment: \pagestyle{fancy} seems to have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to bookmark the 'table of contents' page so that I can return to the content page easily? (according to your given answer) @John Kormylo

Comment: Bookmarking the TOC really has nothing to do with page style.  If you are using hyperref, just use \hypertarget (possibly with \addtocontents or \contentsname) and \hyperlink.

Comment: Ok. I am doing it in this way: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65547/114006

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestion using `\pagestyle{fancyplain}` after loading package `fancyhdr`. Then both pagestyles `fancy` and `plain` under control of `fancyhdr` and `\fancyplain{settings for plain style}{settings for fancy style}` can be used in the argument of `\fancyhf`, `\fancyhead` etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}% <- suggested by fancyhdr
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Team no.}
\fancyhead[R]{Problem no.}
\fancyfoot[C]{\fancyplain{}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}% no pagenumber on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\title{Problem Name}
\author{Team no. \\ Problem no.}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]